# try_files breaks deny in precedent location

Tags: nginx

This bloc

```
location ~ \.php$ {
     deny all;

}
```

works well which blocks **everything** end with .php, and **everywhere** too.

But when this one is added **after** bloc above (which serves static files)

```
location ^~ /cdn/ {

   try_files $uri =404;
   expires 365d;

}
```

cdn/test.php (which exists) will be downloaded, while cdn/test1.php (which not exist) give 404.

I tried adding break; or nested location in cdn but it did not help blocking .php inside cdn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `^~` match character which you are using. With that prefix, nginx does not check regular expression matches after longest prefix matches.

You should get the behaviour you want with this:

```
location /cdn {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 365d;
}
```

Comment: Either "Silly me! " or nginx is hard to master. Thanks alot for your quick answer.